# websocket missing messages and arrive laters

Tags: sockets, websocket

Im new with websocket and read a lot about it.
I want to know that is it posdible that one message does not arrive bot later messages arrive?
this happens in socket io but not in tcp-ip.

Answer (score 0):

TCP guarantees the order of TCP frames sent from one TCP stack to another.  This does not mean message order is guaranteed higher up the stack.  WebSocket, which is built over TCP, does not guarantee WS frame order.  This is the responsibility of the application protocol, e.g., pub/sub, xmpp, db, etc.  Also the receiver needs to check if the WS frame is the only one in a "message" or are there multiple WS frames that comprise the "message".

Btw, I'm using quotes around "message" here because WebSocket is not really a high-level messaging system like ActiveMQ, JMS, AMQP, etc.  Many people loosely say "message" when they talk about WS when they really mean "the data in a WebSocket frame or set of frames".  WebSocket is a low-level transport.  Its like a 'TCP for the web' (not physically, just abstractly speaking).

Most app devs should not use the WebSocket API just like most app devs should not use the raw TCP API.  It looks simple, but you need to develop a lot of code over WS to get the application semantics needed for most applications.

I suggest you use a higher level API that uses WS under the hood.  Lots of possibilities: ActiveMQ, MQTT, NodeJS, Kaazing (the company I work for), et al.